# How to show pop up window in lightning

Tags: lightning

I have a component, which has an image. Onclick of image I want to show up a popup window and in that show values and button. I am able to extract values on click of image, but not able to find how to show them in a new window. 
Below is the sample code
Component

```
<div onclick="{!c.addContact}">
     <c:svg class="slds-icon slds-icon-text-default slds-float--right" 
       xlinkHref="/resource/SLDS100/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#adduser" />
</div>
```

Js Controller

```
addContact : function(component){      

        var action = component.get("c.displayContacts");

         action.setCallback(this, function(a){
          var list = a.getReturnValue();// the list is coming here with values
             alert('length'+ list.length);
             for(i = 0 ; i< list.length(); i++)
             {
                alert('a' list[i].checked); // I want to show the values in the new pop up window or save it another attribute which shows up new component.
             }
        }); 
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
```

Note: The method in the Apex controller writtens a wrapper class list and I want to iterate that list and show its value. Hence I think alert wont work. Can I show a new component as a pop up.
Any quick help will be much appreciated.

Comment: you need to create a modal component as discussed  [here](http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/dynamically-instantiate-and-destroy-lightning-components-modal-dialog-component/)

Comment: I did it using slds-modal div, and using slds-hide to hide and show.

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your code.

```
// for(i = 0 ; i< list.length(); i++)
for(i = 0 ; i< list.length; i++) {
  //alert('a' list[i].checked);
  alert('a' + list[i].checked);
}
```

In my environment, alert works without problems.

Answer (score 0):

`alert` works in Lightning. Your code is failing here:

```
for(i = 0 ; i< list.length(); i++) // change length() to length
```

As an alternative to alert, you can try `force:showToast` 
 if you are in LEX.